# Efficient way to map items from one column into new column in Pandas

Tags: pandas, list, loops, list-comprehension, apply

Let's say if I have a Pandas df called `df_1` where one of the rows looks like this:

| id | rank_url_agg | url_list |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2223 | ['gtech.com','gm.com', 'ford.com'] | ['google.com','gtech.com','autoblog.com','gm.com', 'ford.com'] |

I want to create a new column called `url_list_agg` which does the following things for each row:

- Iterate through the URLs in `url_list`
- If URL doesn't exist in `rank_url_agg` in the same row, assign a value of 0.
- If URL exists in `rank_url_agg`, then *assign the value that corresponds to the difference between the length of the `rank_url_agg` list and the index of that URL in `rank_url_agg`.*
- Once done iterating through all URLs in `url_list`, wrap the results into a list.

So at the end, the first row in the new `url_list_agg` column will become `[0,3,0,2,1]`.

I've tried running the following script (only to test the 1st row and not entire dataframe):

```
for item in agg_report['url_list'][0]:
    if item in agg_report['rank_url_agg'][0]:
        item=len(rank_url_agg[0]) - agg_report['rank_url_agg'][0].index(item)
    else:
        item=0
```

But when I checked `agg_report['url_list'][0]`, it still returned just this list: `['google.com','gtech.com','autoblog.com','gm.com', 'ford.com']`. So my code didn't work.

Any advice on how to achieve this goal for every row in the dataframe will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not assigning back to the actual dataframe.

```
def idx(a, b):
    return [len(a) - a.index(x) if x in a else 0 for x in b]

df_1 = df_1.assign(url_list_agg=[*map(idx, df_1.rank_url_agg, df_1.url_list)])
```

Comment: That's a great point! Thanks and your answer works perfectly!